# Count Above Average

Tags: javascript, arrays, while-loop, arrow-functions

people, just got a quick question about a javascript problem I have. Here is the question posed:

Write a function named countAboveAverage that accepts an array of numbers and returns the count of how many values are more than the average of the same list of numbers. Your countAboveAverage function must call the arrayAverage function you wrote in the previous exercise.
Use the following to test your function.

```js
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 60.8, 28.1];
console.log(countAboveAverage(values)); //expect 3
```

This is what I got so far.

```js
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 60.8, 28.1];
const count = (arr) => {
  let i = 1;
  while(i <= arr){
    i++;
  }
};
const arrayAverage = (arr) => arr.reduce ((a,b) => a+b,0)/arr.length;
const countAboveAverage = (arr) => arrayAverage(arr) ? arrayAverage(arr).count: 0;
console.log(countAboveAverage(values)); //expect 3
```

Obviously it's not working. A little guidance will be much appreciated.

Comment: You might want to carefully examine your syntax. `arrayAverage(arr).count` is not how you call a function

Answer (score 1):

You can store the average value in a variable and then use it to get a count of elements greater than average

```js
const countAboveAverage = (arr) => {
    const average = arrayAverage(arr);
    return arr.filter(i => i > average).length
}
```

`arrayAverage` is the function from your code snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
let values = [31.9, 31.3, 42.4, 42.4, 60.8, 28.1];
const count = (arr) => {
let i = 1;
    while(i <= arr.length){
       i++;
    }

};

const arrayAverage = (arr) => arr.reduce ((a,b) => a+b,0)/arr.length;
const countAboveAverage = (arr) => arrayAverage(arr);

let i=0;
let countAbove=0;

while(i <= values.length){

    if(countAboveAverage(values)<values[i-1]){
      countAbove++;
    }

    i++;
}

countAboveAverage(values)   
console.log(countAbove);
```

Simply This will Work!! :)